# DB Schema for Laravel app recording data-points on arbitrary number of variables

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

My question is about creating a proper schema or way of storing some data I will be collecting.
My app runs Laravel 6.

So I have a number of 'campaigns', an example of which is like this:

```
{
  "campaign_name": "Campaign 1",
  "keywords": ["keyword 1", "keyword 2", "keyword 3"], // there may be hundreds of keywords
  "urls": ["google.com", "bing.com", "example.com"], // there may be many urls
  "business_names": ["Google", "Bing, "Example"], // there may be many business_names
  "locations": [
    {
      "address": "location 1", //this is a postal address
      "lat": "-37.8183",
      "lng": "144.957"
    },
    {
      "address": "location 2", //this is a postal address
      "lat": "-37.7861",
      "lng": "145.312"
    }
    // there may be 50-100 locations.
  ]
}
```

Each url (and each business name) will get matched up with each keyword along with each location.

ie:

```
google.com
  - keyword 1 location 1
  - keyword 1 location 2
  - keyword 1 location 3
  - keyword 2 location 1
  - keyword 2 location 2
// etc etc.  there may be hundreds of keywords and hundreds of locations.

bing.com
  - keyword 1 location 1
  - keyword 1 location 2
  // etc etc as above.
```

Each of these concatenations will have time series data points that I want to store and ultimately query.

I see how a number of tables may be setup to handle this, but is there a way to slightly simplify this by storing some json?

Most of my migrations on projects have been pretty simple with just a single relation but this is a bit harder for me.

Any help is appreciated. I would ideally like to avoid a number of tables and complex pivots or associations if possible (understanding the benefits of normalization...)

Comment: Do you also need to query it later on by location or keyword or any other thing, or it's just a save and get record by AutoIncrement ID?

Comment: I will need to query later by keyword or url/business name.